# Manually set pointer value

Tags: c, pointers, int, pointer-address

i'm working in C.
What I'm trying to do is a function that will return an int containing an address pointing to an object. Then, use the int I received (containing the address), and build a pointer pointing to this address.

Example :

```
MyClass* obj = SomeMethodReturningAPointerOfMyClass();
int address = (int) &obj;
return address;
```

I think it works for this part. The value I get is -4197276. (Maybe I'm totaly wrong?)

Then, on the other part, I'd like to do something like :

```
MyClass* obj = (MyClass*) address;
```

which doesn't work as I can't access any method of obj without getting an error.

---

I found a way to do it :

```
MyClass* obj = SomeMethodReturningAPointerOfMyClass();
machine->registers[2] = (int)obj;
```

then, in the other method where I receive the integer I did :

```
MyClass* obj = (MyClass*)address;
```

I can work on the obj perfectly!
Might not be so clean but it should do the job for what it's used for!

Thanks to everyone who took the time to answer!

Comment: `int`s do not contain memory addresses. Pointers do. Return a pointer. Also, your use of the term "class" implies C++, not C.

Answer (score 6):

First off, *don't do this*. You're getting the address of the *pointer* `obj`, not the object it points to. `obj` is already equal to that address. `&obj` will be some value on the stack (in your case, `0xFFBFF464`) and it will become invalid when your function returns.

Second off, **don't do this**. An `int` is not the C or C++ type for a memory address--a pointer is, and you already have one.

An `int` is not the same as a `MyClass *`. In fact, on 64-bit systems (including most modern PCs), casting a pointer to an integer drops half the pointer's value, and the result is invalid.

If you want your function to return the address of an object, return the pointer:

```
MyClass *GetAnObject(void) {
    MyClass *result = ...;
    return result;
}
```

You should never need to convert a pointer to an integer (there are cases where it's valid, but for newcomers to C, a complete ban is simpler to understand; those edge cases are beyond the scope of this question.)

Comment: Are you a Romulan or a Jem'Hadar? ROMULAN OR JEM'HADAR!? ;p

Comment: Name not a reference to Star Trek? >.>

Comment: Awr. ._. Is it your actual name?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1544/discussion-between-jonathan-grynspan-and-tomalak-geretkal)

Comment: This conversation holds no interest to me so, no, let's not.

Comment: (That was an automated message.) Okay. Sorry about that--no offense intended.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Actually I'm quite aware that it's a pretty wierd move to try to stock the address in an integer. I'm trying to do this because I must send an integer to an assembly language that will store it in a register, which will be accessed by some code I can't modify. The address could then be sent to me again by the same way, and I could then get the same instance and work on it. Anyway, I feel that this thing could cause a lot of problems, so I'll try to figure out another solution! Thanks again

Comment: Well, pointers *are* (on most modern systems) technically integers, so why not just pass the pointer as the integer argument, without any casts at all?

Comment: Alright, thanks, what you said made me try something that works!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, since you are using classes, you are probably working in C++, not in C.

I really wonder why you actually want to store an object pointer in an int?

Regarding your question: depending on the platform, an (object) pointer may not fit in an int. If you cast the pointer to the int, you may simply truncate the pointer value. Now, if you cast back later, the pointer is not complete, and points to some undetermined spot in memory. That can cause problems.

In other words: don't do this. Not only is it very well possible that it fails, it can even cause a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use the `unsigned long` type instead of an `int`, as pointers are 32-bits wide (at least on 32-bit architecture; use `unsigned long long` if you want to be 64-bits aware).

Next, what you store in the `address` variable is not a `MyClass*` but a `MyClass**` as you store the **address of obj** using `&obj` when assigning to `address`... (and `obj` is already of type `MyClass*`)

So you should either store directly the `MyClass*` pointer, or if you want to store the pointer of `MyClass*`, namely a `MyClass**`, you need to indirect it twice by using one more '*' to balance the '&' you wrote when affecting `address`:

```
MyClass* obj = * ((MyClass*)address);
```

Comment: No, `address` in the example is *completely useless* once it's been returned, because it's the address of `obj`, which is a local variable on the stack.  Dereferencing it later will almost certainly just give garbage.

Answer (score 0):

`&obj` returns the address where the pointer `obj` is stored, which isn't quite what you want. The real answer is even simpler:

```
void *obj = SomeMethodReturningAPointerOfMyClass();
return (int) address;
```

Note that this'll break if `int` isn't the same size as a pointer on your system. You may want to pass this around as a `void *`, `intptr_t`, or `long`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your system, `int` may be a poor choice. If you **really have to** pass the pointer as an integral value, you should use `uintptr_t` which is always guaranteed to be as big as a pointer.

Also, `&obj` is probably not what you want. I think you meant `obj`.